# How to fix htaccess config or apache2 install

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I'm trying to put CORS in a PHP api and got this error in my vhost error log

```
[Thu Jun 10 16:41:48.492129 2021] [core:alert] [pid 44869] [client 127.0.0.1:47408] /home/wardog1/work/gitlab/prodcalc/backend/api-accounts/codebase/php/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I'm using:

ubuntu 20
apache2
angular 8

I suspect it's some apache2 config missing

This is what I'm trying

```
RewriteEngine on

# Enable CORS
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, COMPRODCALC_SESSION_ID"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

# Force to request 200 for options
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule .* / [R=200,L]
```

```
$ curl -v -X OPTIONS api-accounts.prodcalc.com
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api-accounts.prodcalc.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-accounts.prodcalc.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 19:50:41 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
< Content-Length: 623
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at api-accounts.prodcalc.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0
```

chrome console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api-accounts.prodcalc.com/person/registerPerson' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: And, have you checked whether the relevant module _is_ included in the server configuration?

Comment: what's the module? how to config?

Comment: This would require the Apache Headers module to be enabled: `sudo a2enmod headers`, then restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`. This should get you going.